# Enabling dl function in PHP 7

Tags: php, nginx, php-7

I just upgraded an application to run on PHP 7 under NGINX. I noticed that one of the included (through Composer) libraries has stopped working, since it uses the `dl` function to load extensions at runtime. After reading the [dl documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) I'm a little bit confused. It claims to support PHP 7, but I don't understand how one should "activate" the function.

It says on the PHP documentation page:

> This function was removed from most SAPIs in PHP 5.3.0, and was removed from PHP-FPM in PHP 7.0.0.

Does that mean that it's not possible to get it working with PHP-FPM?

Comment: The changelog says it's simply disabled (check php.ini and set `enable_dl` to `On`).

Comment: Meanwhile you should encourage the author of the library to not use `dl` as it slows down scripts. http://www.hackingwithphp.com/18/1/17/dont-use-dl